# Android connection to rabbitmq always timeout exception

Tags: android, timeout, rabbitmq

I am trying to test connecting my android code to local rabbitmq server. But, I always encounter the exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException.
How can I solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setUri("amqp://phanna:phanna@172.16.150.85:15672/");
        factory.setConnectionTimeout(6000000);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?